# How to find information about sent transaction that does not show up on Etherscan, Polygonscan or getTransaction API

Tags: web3.py, polygon

Is there a way to figure get more information about a certain transaction from its txn hash? I am noticing lots of stuck transactions. Here is the workflow:

- `txid = web3.eth.send_transaction`
- `web3.get_transaction(txid)` raises `TransactionNotFound` error.

When i search for that `txid` on polygonscan, I don't get anything.

What are the options available to me to debug this? Is the time between `send` and `get` like a blackhole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this means that the node, of which JSON-RPC API you are using, is not broadcasting the transaction to the network.

Reasons may include

- Very incorrect gas fee
- Wrong nonce
- Wrong signature

To debug such problems, run your local JSON-RPC API node, with log level debug. Then submit your transaction against this node and you will see any errors with your transaction in the log files of your node.

Comment: Is there a way to run the JSON-RPC API only without having to download the whole blockchain?

Comment: No. Where would the API get the data in that case, then?

Comment: Ok. I was thinking that for debugging it could forward all the calls to another node.